# Extracting MUST-match and MUST_NOT-match Boolean clauses from an EDismax query

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have a [Query](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html) `q` returned by [ExtendedDismaxQParser](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/ExtendedDismaxQParser.html)'s [parse()](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/ExtendedDismaxQParser.html#parse%28%29) method. I need to generate from that `Query q` a new [BooleanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html) `qNew`. The `BooleanQuery qNew` should consist of:

- a [MUST-match](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause.Occur.html#MUST) Boolean clause for each MUST-match clause in the original `Query q`.
- a [MUST_NOT-match](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause.Occur.html#MUST_NOT) Boolean clause for each MUST_NOT-match clause in the original `Query q`.
- a single [SHOULD-match](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause.Occur.html#SHOULD) Boolean clause consisting of the rest of the original `Query q`.
- Other certain SHOULD-match clauses I might need to add.

For example, if the `Query q` is `a +b c +d -e -f g` and the other certain clauses are `x`, `y` and `z` then the new `BooleanQuery qNew` should be `(a c g) +b +d -e -f x y z`.

In order to generate that `BooleanQuery qNew` I need to extract all the MUST-match and MUST_NOT-match Boolean clauses from the original `Query q`, which would have been easy had `q` been a `BooleanQuery`. I looked at the ExtendedDismax [parse() method code](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/trunk/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/ExtendedDismaxQParser.java), and the returned `Query q`'s dynamic type can be either a [BooleanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html) or a [BoostedQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/function/BoostedQuery.html). Is there a general way to perform that transformation from the `Query q` returned by ExtendedDismax `parse()` method to the new `BooleanQuery qNew`?

**Clarification:** The original `Query q` doesn't necessarily consists of any MUST-match, MUST_NOT-match or SHOULD-match clauses. As a matter of fact, the original `Query q` can be any `Query` that can be returned by `ExtendedDismaxQParser`'s `parse()` method. Queries such as `a b c` and `a b -c` shuold be transformed into `(a b c) x y z` and `(a b) -c x y z` respectively. Therefore, wrapping the original query in a MUST-match clause of a Boolean query and add those `x`, `y` and `z` clauses (as suggested in a comment) wouldn't solve the problem in such cases.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Aren't `a +b c +d -e -f g` and `(a c g) +b +d -e -f` effectively identical?  Couldn't you just wrap the whole parsed query in a boolean query, and have the final representation of your query be:  `+(a +b c +d -e -f g) x y z`?

Comment: @femtoRgon: As to what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm trying to implement a sort of query expansion. As to your suggestion: Wrapping the whole parsed query in a Boolean query and adding the `x`, `y` and `z` clauses does work in the above example (`+(a +b c +d -e -f g) x y z` is indeed equivalent to `(a c g) +b +d -e -f x y z`). But it wouldn't work when the original query doesn't have any MUST-match clauses. For example, if the original query is `a -b` then the method you've suggested generates `+(a -b) x y z` which is not equivalent to `a -b x y z`. I'll add a clarification to my question.

Comment: Right.  Generally when I've seen this sort of thing, it only makes sense to get results that match something in the parsed query.  In this case, you run into the problem that there aren't a lot of assumptions you can make about the Query returned from the parse.  You could traverse through `BoostedQuery.getQuery()`, and hope you find a `BooleanQuery`, but you might not. You could find a `DisjunctionMaxQuery`, or even just a `TermQuery`, among many other possibilities.  I'm inclined to treat a parsed query as atomic.  It might be simpler to just add your terms to the query string, if possible.